# How to slide images which are coming from http url?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I am trying to make an application in which images are coming from server, i want to make an image slider from that images. To achieve this i referred from [here](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/)  and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) but i am getting error

My `ImageAdapter.java`

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    String[] imagUrl={"http://www.vector-eps.com/wp-content/gallery/donald-duck-vectors/thumbs/thumbs_donald-duck-vectors11.jpg",
            "http://www.vector-eps.com/wp-content/gallery/donald-duck-vectors/thumbs/thumbs_donald-duck-vectors11.jpg",
            "http://www.vector-eps.com/wp-content/gallery/donald-duck-vectors/thumbs/thumbs_donald-duck-vectors11.jpg"};


    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagUrl.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        int loader = R.drawable.ic_cancel;

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(imagUrl[position], loader, imageView );
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Here's the `ImageLoader.java`

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_cancel;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, int loader, ImageView imageView)
    {
        stub_id = loader;
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(loader);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

And the `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

The LogCat is

```
09-05 14:59:49.765 8364-8364/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
09-05 14:59:49.795 8364-8372/com.example.pitech09.slidee E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
09-05 14:59:49.795 8364-8372/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-05 14:59:50.820 8364-8364/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-05 14:59:51.071 8364-8416/com.example.pitech09.slidee D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-05 14:59:51.081 8364-8364/com.example.pitech09.slidee D/Atlas: Validating map...
09-05 14:59:51.129 8364-8416/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8610_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                       Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
                                                                       Local Branch: 
                                                                       Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
                                                                       Local Patches: NONE
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
09-05 14:59:51.130 8364-8416/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-05 14:59:51.148 8364-8416/com.example.pitech09.slidee D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-05 14:59:51.254 8364-8364/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-05 14:59:58.706 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TempImages/-1563297368: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 14:59:58.706 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:77)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:26)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:137)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
09-05 14:59:58.707 8364-8954/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:  ... 10 more
09-05 14:59:58.816 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TempImages/-1563297368: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 14:59:58.816 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:77)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:26)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:137)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
09-05 14:59:58.817 8364-8953/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:  ... 10 more
09-05 15:01:41.300 8364-8372/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-05 15:07:17.204 8364-8372/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/art: Debugger is no longer active
09-05 15:11:03.084 29993-29993/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-05 15:11:03.332 29993-30065/com.example.pitech09.slidee D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-05 15:11:03.345 29993-29993/com.example.pitech09.slidee D/Atlas: Validating map...
09-05 15:11:03.458 29993-30065/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8610_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                         Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
                                                                         Local Branch: 
                                                                         Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
                                                                         Local Patches: NONE
                                                                         Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
09-05 15:11:03.464 29993-30065/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-05 15:11:03.508 29993-30065/com.example.pitech09.slidee D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-05 15:11:03.513 29993-30006/com.example.pitech09.slidee I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18529(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 9(170KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 5MB/8MB, paused 5.840ms total 113.009ms
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TempImages/-1563297368: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:77)
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:26)
09-05 15:11:03.972 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:137)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 15:11:03.973 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-05 15:11:03.975 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
09-05 15:11:03.975 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
09-05 15:11:03.975 29993-30066/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:    ... 10 more
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TempImages/-1563297368: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:77)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:26)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at com.example.pitech09.slidee.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:137)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 15:11:04.088 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-05 15:11:04.089 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
09-05 15:11:04.089 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
09-05 15:11:04.089 29993-30067/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/System.err:    ... 10 more
09-05 15:11:15.361 29993-30001/com.example.pitech09.slidee W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.336ms
```

I've added the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your Manifest.xml?

Comment: yes , this are the permission which i have included -     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: Are you testing on `6.0 Marshmallow` ?

Comment: No, i am testing on Android Version 5.1

Comment: @Kritiii Try with adding this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` seems give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Universal Image Loader so you have follow this Quick setup instruction, please read [UIL Quick Setup](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup).
Please read Android Manifest setting its says that your application manifest must have Internet and External Storage permission. so you have to add both permission on you AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And if you are working on api laval 23 you must have to ask runtime permission first before using Universal Image Loader. Please read official documentation for more detail.
[Runtime Permission Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)